# Trying to end a loop with 10 of the lowest values out of more

Tags: php, sorting

I have code already that loops through each member of my website and can retrieve a particular variable (in this case it is $duration).

What I am trying to do is find people with the 10 lowest *durations*, and put them into an ordered array or list and then loop through the 10 and `echo` it out.

As a use case, let's pretend that out of 100 members, 10 people have *duration* 10, 20, 30, 40, etc..., and we'll pretend the other 90 members have *durations* somewhere between 101-1000.

As I loop through each member, I want to see if that member's *duration* value is lower than any of the 10 I already have in some container (array?), and at the end be able to `echo` out the 10 from lowest to highest.

Comment: Sort the list of all members by duration and iterate over the first ten.

Comment: Is this data in a database (MySQL or similar)? If it is, could you not order the data as part of the database query?

Comment: Where do you get your data from? If you're using a database of some kind, it's probably easier and faster to write another query than it is to retrieve all the members and loop through them using PHP.

Comment: Maybe I should add ALL the values to an array, and then sort and echo only the first 10 using a for loop?

Comment: My values' origin starts in a member's profile, but is then used as a lookup for another website's API, and I'm receiving data from XML. It won't be as easy as me sorting a database, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: What you want is a "partial sort" algorithm -- C++ has one in the standard library, but I can't see one in PHP. Basically that's an algorithm that only provides the first _k_ sorted members of a collection of _n_ elements and leaves the remaining elements in unspecified order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have to loop through every value anyway, just add all of the values to an array and then use the `sort` method and take the first ten items (0-9).  Here is the documentation on how exactly to use this method:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

The benefit of this solution is that it will re-order the values so that key 0 corresponds with the lowest value.  It also has the option  to change what type of comparison you are doing (text, numeric, etc.)

You could try to sort every time you find a new value (insert the new value and drop the highest value).  That would save you the memory storage for the array but it will cost you in processing power when you do a comparison on each value.  Even with optimization it probably won't be good enough.

If you really didn't want to put every item in the array, you could create an array of 50 members (or whatever magic number you wanted to use).  You could populate it with the first 50 durations and then sort it.  Then you could add 40 more items to array positions 10-49 and sort it again.  You could repeat that over and over, keeping your lowest ten items every time you add new durations.  That way you could balance the performance hit of sorting every item with the memory hit of storing every item.  You could dial it in by changing the array size.

Comment: This is the solution I am taking. During the gathering of data, I use functions such as !empty() to start eliminating users that don't have the value defined at all. This increases performance by not bothering to even add those user's to the array for sorting.

Comment: I'm gonna do this http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/sortarray/ to finish off my project. Your solution helped me though and thats the way i'm doing it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See this example in codepad: http://codepad.org/4ROaojCT

```
<?php

$array = array(5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13);

sort($array);
$array = array_slice($array, 0, 10);

print_r($array);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Store all the members of your website in a Hash with the key being the duration and the value being a primary key or even an object containing the member's detail. Write a function that can be fed to [uksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) which will sort the hash based on the keys. reverse and print the top 10.